# How do I restrict context menus to appear only for certain selected text in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I made a very simple [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/goanbaknlbojfglcepjnankoobfakbpg) which allows users to highlight a DOI number, right-click and choose "Resolve DOI", and it sends them to the associated web page. Right now, this is done in background.html with:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
"title" : "Resolve DOI",
"type" : "normal",
"contexts" : ["selection"],
"onclick" : getClickHandler()
});
```

I would like to restrict the context menu option to only appear if the text they highlight begins with "10." Any suggestions on how to do this? Do I need to wait for the Context Menus module to become more advanced?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would need to control content menu creation from a content script. Dynamic menu creation/deletion should execute pretty fast and the delay will be unnoticeable for a user.

- Add mousedown event listener in a content script and check there whether selection satisfies your pattern.
- Based on whether or not selection matches the patterrn, send a request to a background page asking to create or delete the menu.

Something along those lines (not tested):

**content_script.js:**

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    if(selection.match(/^10\./)) {
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "create_menu"});
    } else {
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "delete_menu"});
    }
}, true);
```

**background.html:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request) {
    if(request.cmd == "create_menu") {
        chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(function() {
            chrome.contextMenus.create({
                "title" : "Resolve DOI",
                "type" : "normal",
                "contexts" : ["selection"],
                "onclick" : getClickHandler()
            });
        });
    } else if(request.cmd == "delete_menu") {
        chrome.contextMenus.removeAll();
    }
});
```

Comment: Terrific.  Tested and working with no modification needed.  Thank you so much.  This also gives me an introduction to listeners so that I can make my options page apply changes immediately.

Comment: There seems to be some issues with https pages. The content_script.js isn't filtering correctly. As an example:
This page and the page of my extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/goanbaknlbojfglcepjnankoobfakbpg) are both open. I select text which contains "10." on this page and the menu is created.  I move to the other tab and select any text, and the menu still exists.  I move back to this page, select any non-"10." text, and the menu disappears.  Moving back to the https tab, regardless of whether I make a valid selection the menu will not appear.

Comment: @mdmower Content scripts are disabled on webstore pages for security reasons (same goes for old extension gallery site)

Comment: `mousedown` does not fire when someone opens the context menu with the keyboard.

Comment: chrome.extension.sendRequest() is deprecated as of Chrome 33 in favor of runtime.sendMessage().  See: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-sendRequest