# Chrome extension: add option to right click menu when clicking certain HTML element

Tags: google-chrome-extension, right-click

I want to create a Chrome extension that adds an option to the right click menu when the user right  clicks a certain HTML element (for example a DIV with a known ID).

I would use this to add an option when the user right clicks a tweet on Twitter.com and that option would call a REST service.

Is this posible with a regultar Chrome extension?

Comment: that is not possible I think, but you can create and delete the items when clicking depending on the element clicked, as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730843/how-do-i-restrict-context-menus-to-appear-only-for-certain-selected-text-in-a-ch

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, these are called Context Menus. You can find the docs for those here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus

Comment: I posted the same thing earlier, then deleted, because I realized he actually wants to actually add custom HTML to the context menu, and I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I don't think this is a complete answer because the documentation you link to is not clear enough.  For example, what parameters should we pass to chrome.contextMenus.create to restrict the menu item to only show up on elements with an ID equal to `"foobar"`?

Comment: that is not possible I think, but you can create and delete the items when clicking depending on the element clicked, as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730843/how-do-i-restrict-context-menus-to-appear-only-for-certain-selected-text-in-a-ch

Answer (score 5):

Use chrome.contextMenus to add the option to right click

```js
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: 'test',
    onclick: function(e){
        console.log(e)
    }

}, function(){})
```