# Chrome Extension Save File Dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Please I am new to building Chrome Extensions. After the user installs the extension, I want them to configure it by specifying a directory where the app can save files. I want to do this by opening a save file dialog so they can browse to the folder of their choice. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that there is no means in the Chrome Extension API to write files outside of the sandboxed file system provided by Chrome. This could theoretically be done by writing an interface in C and then call that, but so far I have not yet seen a successful implementation.

Comment: THanks a lot. Ive decided to just make it a form that asks the user to enter what ever path they want. How do modify Chrome so that whenever my extension is running, there is an extra option in chrome's right-click menu? So say my app is enabled, i want to be able to rightclick on any image and see "speedsave" in the menu. clicking that option saves the image to that location they specified in the app.

Comment: Greetings, for that, you can check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462900/chrome-extension-add-option-to-right-click-menu-when-clicking-certain-html-elem/11463132#11463132